.net core scoped service problem in repository
I have a .net core 8 site where i have a number of services and repositories.
This is setup by using dependency injection.
I now have created a Background service that will use som of the service and repos.
In my background service a have created a scope and gotten the service I need.
 using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
 {
     var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMailService>();
     await SendMail(scopedService, stoppingToken);
     await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
 }

This works fine but when i need to call my IMailRepositry from IMailService i get an error because IMailRepositry is not scored within IMailService.
I can fix this an create a scope in IMailRepositry, but is the really necessary?
Is there som way to make .net know that i started the call from a scoped service everything under it should be runned i same scope?
I hope the question make sense :)

Yes, it's necessary. This has nothing do to with the repository pattern. BackgroundService and all hosted services are singletons. To use a scoped service you have to define a scope. This is explained in the docs: Consuming a scoped service in a background task.

There are a lot of duplicate questions too, although most of them ask specifically for DbContext, which, as a Unit-of-Work, is inherently scoped. It doesn't matter what the implementation is though. To use scoped services inside a singleton , you need a scope, or create a "factory" class that creates service instances. Making the background service scoped or transient isn't a solution, because who's going to restart that service every time 10 seconds?

PS if you want to automate email sending, it's a lot better to use a library like Coravel, Hangfire or Quartz.NET. Coravel was built for email scheduling from the start while the others are more generic

@PanagiotisKanavos its a incomplete code example-
There is a lot more logic then sending mails  and the job will just run every 30 min
Thanks for the answar
